# Deleting nth line of multiple text files with SED - not working for me on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sed

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION

> Thanks to @KamilCuk, @Jetchisel and @chepner for explaining it in a way that made sense

First, apologies for any noobness. I am not a coder. I am currently using OSX 10.14.6 and the OSX standard terminal.

Short issue:

```
sed '5d' *.txt
```

is NOT deleting the 5th line of each text file in a directory.

**Background**

I have thousands of plain text news articles that I will be using to conduct a corpus analysis. As such, I want to strip irrelevant text information from the files.

The articles are all in the following format (line numbers added for clarity):

```
1. <blank line>
2. <article heading>
3. <date> 
4. <blank line>
5. Body
```

The word "Body" always occurs at line 5, is always capitalised, and is always by itself.

I want to strip either only line 5, or only lines that have the word "Body" by itself (as the articles will almost certainly include the word "Body" in them).

From reading a lot of pages, the following should work:

```
sed '5d' file
```

So, in my case:

```
sed '5d' *.txt
```

However, this is not working for me, nor any other variation I have tried (using either * or *.txt).

```
sed -i '5d' *.txt

sed -i '' '5d' *.txt

sed -e '5d' *.txt
```

Invariably it deletes the 5th line of the FIRST file, but none of the rest of the files in the directory, so SOMETHING is working.

Alternatively, is there a way to specify deleting the string "Body" when it is the only word on a line?

Clearly I have the wrong end of the stick here, so any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you established a fact: The call `sed 5d *.txt` deleted 5th line of the first file. So maybe, instead, call `sed 5d` for each file in the folder - that way each file will be the first.

Comment: This is what I am a bit confused about: the deleting of the lines using -e and a string, '/StringGoesHere/d' worked on all the files.

using 'NUMd' doesn't appear to be operating the same way.

Is there a difference between: 


`sed -i  '' -e '/Northern Territory News (Australia)/d' *.txt`

and


`sed -i  '' -e '5d' *.txt`

in terms of how they operate on files?

Comment: The difference is that your implementation of `sed` just increments like numbers. So when a new file is opened, line numbers are just bigger, so there is only one line number 5, in the first file (well, unless first file has less then 5 lines). It works as if `cat *.txt | sed 5d`. With a pattern you don't care about line numbers.... `I don't want to remove lines with the string, "Body"` Just remove lines containing only the word Body and nothing else.

Comment: Is the string `Body` you want to delete is always the start/beginning of the line?

Comment: @DoubleSupercool What is the point of this? What should the result be? Please post expected output you want to get from the input you presented. Why not just filter lines between two patterns `Body` and `Load-date` not caring about anything else?

Comment: Apologies, guys. I have edited my post to hopefully make it clearer what I am trying to achieve.

@KamilCuk, re: cat, that makes a lot more sense now: it is essentially parsing all the text files as one file, so there can only be one "line" 5. Thanks for your explanation. The ultimate aim is to delete the word "Body", either in that position in the file, or when it is by itself.

Comment: Apologies, guys. I have edited my post to hopefully make it clearer what I am trying to achieve.


@Jetchisel ; yes, it is always at the beginning of the first line and always the only word on the line.

Comment: `for file in *.txt; do sed '/^Body$/d' "$file";  done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the POSIX specification:

> An address is either a decimal number that counts input lines **cumulatively** across files, a '$' character that addresses the last line of input, or a context address (which consists of a BRE, as described in Regular Expressions in sed, preceded and followed by a delimiter, usually a ).

So the command `5d` only deletes the 5th line of the files taken as a whole, but you want the 5th line of *each* file.

I don't see anyway to "reset" the address, so you'll have to specify a context address.

```
sed -i '' '/^Body$/d' *.txt
```

This will delete each line that consists only of the word `Body`; the `^` matches the beginning of a line, the `$` the end.

---

Alternatively, just run `sed` separately for each file.

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -i '' '5d' "$f"; done
```